# как исправить ошибку voln(0,0) F if i < n and lab[i+1][j]==0 : TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
     n=int(input())
 lab=[]*n
 for i in range (n):
     lab+=[int (i) for i in input().split()]
 def voln (i,j):
     global n
     if i < n and lab[i+1][j]==0 :
         lab[i+1][j]=8
         voln(i+1,j)
     elif j < n and lab[i][j+1]==0 :
         lab[i][j+1]=8
         voln(i+1,j)
     elif i > 0 and lab[i-1][j]==0 :
         lab[i-1][j]=8
         voln(i-1,j)
     elif j > 0 and lab[i][j-1]==0 :
         lab[i][j-1]=8
         voln(i,j-1)
 voln(0,0)
 print(lab)
```

Answer (score 1):

тут все просто, конструкцией

```
lab+=[int (i) for i in input().split()]
```

вы добавляете в *lab* элементы из получившегося после ввода списка, в итоге он выглядит так

> пусть ввод - 1 2 3, 4 5 6

тогда *lab* станет:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6]
```

чтобы такого не было, воспользуйтесь такой конструкцией

```
lab.append([int(i) for i in input().split()])
```